Error typescript when returning something different than "this" in knex extend function
Problem
I'm trying to extend knex with a function that would return something that is not the queryBuilder instance. I guess the same way that .toSQL() returns an object that is not the queryBuilder.
However I'm having a typescript error. I'm not a typescript expert and I wonder if I can solve this problem or if a typescript change is needed in the knex library.
My code:
import Knex from 'knex'
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

Knex.QueryBuilder.extend('toPrismaSql', function() {
  const { bindings, sql } = this.toSQL()
  
  if (sql.includes('??')) {
    throw new Error(`Cannot convert identifiers ??. SQL query: ${sql}`)
  }

  return Prisma.sql(sql.split('?'), ...bindings)
})

export const knex = Knex({ client: 'postgres' })


The typescript error:
Argument of type
<
  TRecord extends {} = any,
  TResult extends {} = unknown[]
>(
  this: QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>
) => Sql

is not assignable to parameter of type

<
  TRecord extends {} = any,
  TResult extends {} = unknown[]
>(
  this: QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>,
  ...args: any[]
) => QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>
  | Promise<Resolve<TResult> | QueryBuilder<TRecord | TResult, any>>

Type 'Sql' is not assignable to type 'QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult> | Promise<Resolve<TResult> | QueryBuilder<TRecord | TResult, any>>

ts(2345)

You can test the code there: https://replit.com/@replit77i18/Knex-extend-typescript-error#index.ts

return Pisma.sql(...) return something of type Sql, but QueryBuilder need to return 'QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult> | Promise<Resolve<TResult> | QueryBuilder<TRecord | TResult, any>>.
Is there a way to transform the SQL restult of Prisma.sql() into one of those types?

I was wondering if I can tell typescript TResult = Sql. But I'm not sure how the generic type works, I tried some things but it didn't work. It seems to me TResult is already defined before.
